# What is wrong with this query? None of the returned data is correct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to figure this query out for two days.

First, let me say that I am new to development and so it may be a simple query but I just cannot figure it out. I have searched on this website trying to find a solution, but if there is one that is similar, I just don't understand it.

What I am trying to do is get some numbers from a database. I need the total number of users, the distinct users, the number of messages received and number of messages sent as well as emails that were collected, phone numbers that were collected and users that subscribed. All of this data has to be associated with a specific account_id. Here is where I am with my query.

```
select COUNT(r.uid) as total_users,COUNT(DISTINCT(r.uid)) as unique_users,  COUNT(r.message) as messages, COUNT(s.message) as messages_sent,
count(ps.email) as emails_collected, 
count(ps.phone_number) as phone_nums_collected,
count(ps.added) as new_users
from conversation_facebook_page_received r
INNER JOIN conversation_facebook_page_sent s ON r.account_id = s.account_id
INNER JOIN conversation_facebook_page_subscribers ps on r.account_id = ps.account_id
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(r.received_time / 1000)) > "2018-01-01 00:00:00" AND r.account_id =616646015120462;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `conversation_facebook_page_received` (
  `account_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `msg_timestamp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `received_time` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `flow_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `step_id` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`,`uid`,`msg_timestamp`),
  KEY `flow_id` (`flow_id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`,`uid`,`received_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `conversation_facebook_page_received` (`account_id`, `uid`, `msg_timestamp`, `received_time`, `flow_id`, `step_id`, `message_id`, `message_type`, `message`)
VALUES
    (616646015120462,2503924196379227,1584982039136,1584982040232,NULL,NULL,NULL,'postback','Get Started'),
    (616646015120462,2503924196379227,1584982386400,1584982387189,NULL,NULL,'m_9X57kg_kRU4_WNXOFvt2QMglfcLimk7CpqvcjtCEbgZYdyYCx-Q5Z4OD_0XmRQzDCshgWcqGBHu7gt_aEhZRmw','text','thank you Bill you are doing the right thing. thank you.  please please lets stop these public gatherings NOW like Barnry Fife would say lets nip it in the bud  so far we been doing pretty good. lets step up our protection this is a must to defeat and win this war with the invisible enemy. i am seeing some school students treating this like  a vacation. they think they are invincible i guess as we did at that age. but somehow this needs enforcing maybe curfew will handle it.  lets stand proud and be protective please'),
    (85825440048,2503924196379227,1584983030585,1584983031341,NULL,NULL,NULL,'postback','Where are you located?'),
    (85825440048,2503924196379227,1584983047452,1584983048370,NULL,NULL,'m_xmK7lKY_86EIlS8dIQuRWMglfcLimk7CpqvcjtCEbgYaKd5ju8Nxscj78YjQWMUMFQkDZ161flNUZkLzZcDLgQ','text','moultrie ga'),
    (85825440048,2612891932156066,1586146320864,1586146321550,NULL,NULL,'m_4SNxwBOETFo3AEkxrRI_aNp0bwZ0kZj3tHm2Pjjq-Pk0SlZiIJrBlXMzdWPdpF80V2Bxw5rn9W34Yihs5oUUrA','text','could be useful'),
    (616646015120462,2792591144203564,1586896951790,1586896953965,NULL,NULL,NULL,'postback','Get Started'),
    (85825440048,3024889994213410,1587234572314,1587234572945,NULL,NULL,NULL,'postback','Get Started'),
    (85825440048,3278699712163817,1590010576412,1590010577520,NULL,NULL,NULL,'postback','Get Started'),
    (85825440048,3300581309974788,1587015278753,1587015279577,NULL,NULL,NULL,'postback','Get Started');

    CREATE TABLE `conversation_facebook_page_sent` (
  `account_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `flow_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `step_id` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `send_time` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_time` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `read_time` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `click_time` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `messaging_type` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  KEY `flow_id` (`flow_id`),
  KEY `message_id` (`message_id`,`delivery_time`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`,`uid`,`send_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `conversation_facebook_page_sent` (`account_id`, `uid`, `flow_id`, `step_id`, `send_time`, `delivery_time`, `read_time`, `click_time`, `message_id`, `messaging_type`, `tag`, `message`)
VALUES
  (616646015120462,2560048887396840,311,12,1583776598792,NULL,NULL,NULL,'k9Y48rBJ00rEt3pQB6WKnYcxhm_DmqdBwkxj2rJUQw1qrWJ2mTK676jH4oKNxSYR_SaK9caNXgXmebCkMGWucA','RESPONSE',NULL,'{\"attachment\":{\"type\":\"template\",\"payload\":{\"template_type\":\"button\",\"text\":\"Enter the BarkyPark  Sweepstakes and answer a simple 1 question survey to win a prize for you and your dog!\\nAre you ready to get started?\",\"buttons\":[{\"type\":\"postback\",\"title\":\"Get Me Started!\",\"payload\":\"254f28383a5e5d495561414039273859\"}]}}}'),
  (135613753250298,2681220635324690,382,2,1583778926385,1585072862424,NULL,NULL,'3lVOWAVsPtPrezfsfVmp4KLNDO4MLhlMAzKDQb7H-NqsvIZNa218b4nbGFUW-UfIcmYYXRTpZYsYpYJ0q68P8A','RESPONSE',NULL,'{\"text\":\"Just enter or tap your email address below to join our online \'ohana & receive discounts, secret offers and free stuff!\",\"quick_replies\":[{\"content_type\":\"user_email\"}]}'),
  (135613753250298,2681220635324690,382,5,1583778959043,1585072862424,NULL,NULL,'RvG5e69Dz6tamKYfRS6G5KLNDO4MLhlMAzKDQb7H-Nq8BA4sTK9Fooj1-hKb57SGSa7kYfpHEq68lP4Y4f6iYQ','RESPONSE',NULL,'{\"text\":\"You\'re all set! Go to your inbox to find your secret 15% coupon code! Mahalo for your support and welcome to the \'ohana!\"}'),
  (616646015120462,3452199664850501,382,2,1583780413556,NULL,NULL,NULL,'TyMsC7YuxGm1rj7Bsm_wCldXcpdYq_M6kRBtcWnLwNnv3xNUd7-WC0ANAebVwnD14ld3vagpMiSmoKgbAwvPMw','RESPONSE',NULL,'{\"text\":\"Just enter or tap your email address below to join our online \'ohana & receive discounts, secret offers and free stuff!\",\"quick_replies\":[{\"content_type\":\"user_email\"}]}'),
  (135613753250298,3452199664850501,382,5,1583780425764,NULL,NULL,NULL,'fArsI5l7Kfi_ys7KteuCcldXcpdYq_M6kRBtcWnLwNkQ58PZesvFKfYoaIpXoIH6qQR-RmVmd4LZ8Sm3KYHjOw','RESPONSE',NULL,'{\"text\":\"You\'re all set! Go to your inbox to find your secret 15% coupon code! Mahalo for your support and welcome to the \'ohana!\"}'),
  (616646015120462,2916614285069775,382,2,1583782640116,NULL,NULL,NULL,'XqLkq7eq2-eorH0YUNOb1PQyrq48TiSkKb3IzaXtI_MoMC2zRu1Y8g7wdX21vyobi8Xqs5UxRMCwS4HsPzjpPg','RESPONSE',NULL,'{\"text\":\"Just enter or tap your email address below to join our online \'ohana & receive discounts, secret offers and free stuff!\",\"quick_replies\":[{\"content_type\":\"user_email\"}]}'),
  (135613753250298,2916614285069775,382,5,1583782662572,NULL,NULL,NULL,'5sfoANj_a6wY9r6uBcGq9PQyrq48TiSkKb3IzaXtI_NnU8xY5WCqGUxzwgPGAbNCRjeXCFaS1ROO89rPSARkQw','RESPONSE',NULL,'{\"text\":\"You\'re all set! Go to your inbox to find your secret 15% coupon code! Mahalo for your support and welcome to the \'ohana!\"}'),
  (135613753250298,2573340896108684,382,2,1583783558954,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2OtlgFNwcp7kXDD2fOneT9LlZVZ3bAkwnrR1oPc20zX1psaItIi2yt9HaXYXFQJgC_eZ68Rm-0uKPtW-cQKLSA','RESPONSE',NULL,'{\"text\":\"Just enter or tap your email address below to join our online \'ohana & receive discounts, secret offers and free stuff!\",\"quick_replies\":[{\"content_type\":\"user_email\"}]}'),
  (135613753250298,2573340896108684,382,5,1583783573525,NULL,NULL,NULL,'bdqtU1VsVI6RmDgshnN-dtLlZVZ3bAkwnrR1oPc20zWrEU-LOyW7WnoraCIlC6UgiMP9Nces8R1UEjJk-E4J5g','RESPONSE',NULL,'{\"text\":\"You\'re all set! Go to your inbox to find your secret 15% coupon code! Mahalo for your support and welcome to the \'ohana!\"}');


  CREATE TABLE `conversation_facebook_page_subscribers` (
  `account_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscribed` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_contact` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `unsubscribe` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`,`uid`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`,`last_contact`,`subscribed`,`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `conversation_facebook_page_subscribers` (`account_id`, `uid`, `name`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone_number`, `profile_pic`, `subscribed`, `added`, `last_contact`, `unsubscribe`)
VALUES
  (616646015120462,1162227020568661,'My Name','My','Name',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2019-10-06 11:04:35','2019-10-06 11:34:45',NULL),
  (616646015120462,1964363690254660,'Some Name','Some','Name',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2019-03-26 21:53:56','2019-05-01 15:25:34',NULL),
  (616646015120462,2118450464865475,'John Doe','John','Doe',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2019-01-16 20:04:25','2019-05-01 15:25:34',NULL),
  (85825440048,2170134986379371,'Andrew Stokes','Andrew','Stokes',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2019-01-22 02:22:41','2019-05-01 15:25:34',NULL),
  (616646015120462,2198986756859748,'Frank Kroger','Frank','Kroger',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2019-05-08 00:47:13','2019-12-24 06:45:09',NULL),
  (85825440048,2274994739293368,'Paul Briggs','Paul','Briggs',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2019-10-16 22:34:28','2019-10-16 22:37:08',NULL),
  (616646015120462,2485007991552080,'Pawan Bhamu','Pawan','Bhamu',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2019-05-20 22:42:49','2019-05-20 23:07:53',NULL),
  (85825440048,2503924196379227,'Scott Pettyjohn','Scott','Pettyjohn',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2020-03-23 16:47:20','2020-03-23 17:04:08',NULL),
  (85825440048,2530973936973839,'Firas M. Alameh','Firas','Alameh',NULL,NULL,NULL,1,'2019-03-11 07:21:03','2019-05-01 15:25:34',NULL);
```

Additionally, I have created a fiddle at db-fiddle.com.

The URL for the fiddle is https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gqJBR8u3ziiK4rXRYGHpVF/1. In the fiddle, I only have 10 rows, yet if you run the fiddle, it returns 45 total users, 2 unique users, 45 messages, etc. Numbers that are impossible to be correct.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I want to understand SQL, but apparently I don't understand it or I wouldn't be getting such distorted numbers.
Thank you in advance for any assistance you can give me. Please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you are getting more rows than you're expecting, check if there are duplicates in the table you're joining. eg. if there are multiple rows with the same account_id(as it is the joining key) in conversation_facebook_page_received ,conversation_facebook_page_sent or conversation_facebook_page_subscribers . Also check if you've missed adding any filter.

Comment: There are rows in each table with account_id. But that is what I am joining with and there are only 10 rows in the fiddle. Yet, I am getting a result of 45. So, not sure that I am following you in your comment. Sorry, I just don't understand.

Comment: First aggregate, then join!

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not a function!!!** Write `COUNT(DISTINCT r.uid)` to make code clearer!

Comment: Make it easy to assist you. Sample data like 1, 2, 3 etc are much easier to read than 616646015120462, 616646013120462, 616546015120462 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select r.account_id, COUNT(r.uid) as total_users,COUNT(DISTINCT(r.uid)) as
unique_users,  COUNT(r.message) as messages, COUNT(s.message) as messages_sent,
count(ps.email) as emails_collected, 
count(ps.phone_number) as phone_nums_collected,
count(ps.added) as new_users
from conversation_facebook_page_received r
left JOIN conversation_facebook_page_sent s ON r.account_id = s.account_id and
r.uid=s.uid
left JOIN conversation_facebook_page_subscribers ps on r.account_id = ps.account_id 
and r.uid=ps.uid
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(r.received_time / 1000)) > "2018-01-01 00:00:00" AND  
r.account_id =616646015120462
group by r.account_id;
```

The join with account_id is not enought to select a single row, as it appears in more rows in every table, ad added the "uid" join and made the LEFT JOIN, so you got every message one time, but if a combination of account_ID and uid do not exist in one table (ie: not all the uid have subscribed) you can count their message anyway.
The e-mail and phone numer are 0.. cause you insert them NULL in the data...

Comment: That does seem to be closer to what I am looking for. However, I added a couple of email addresses and phone numbers into the fiddle to more accurately simulate my real dataset and still getting 0 with them. However, the other fields seem to be returning correctly now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've checked your updated fiddle. The e-mail doesn't come out because it's on a uid not related to the account_id. Plus, as the query is done, the subcribed e-mail must be on a uid that have received a message. I assumed i uid at least receive a message to be "scheduled", than it can send a message or subscribe… if it is not like that you need a table whit the existing relations between Account_id and uid, and use that table as first and left join all the Others the that

Comment: You are right. I thought I had updated the uid so that there would be some matching records, but obviously I had not done so. Thank you very much for your help. Accepting your answer now.